# Reading the cause of death for an acute type of pneumonia

Tags: cause-of-death

I received a death certificate today for my wife's Great Grandmother. Poor lady died at the young age of 47. Ouch - I am 47 in April! Ooer ...

This is the cause of death:

[image: Cause Death]

I read it as:

> a. Acute **?????** Pneumonia
>
> b. Cardiac Failure
>
> c. Influenza
>
> No P.M.

I can't work out what the second word is.

Comment: Got it - LOBAR.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobar_pneumonia

Comment: You can write an answer to your own question. Self-answering is both permitted and encouraged. Just be sure to write a minimum of a few sentences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a side note - the causes should be read from (c) to (a).

So she was suffering from influenza, which led to cardiac failure, which in turn caused acute [lobar pneumonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobar_pneumonia) (which was the actual cause of death).